# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (25x7 and 1x512)

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, time-series, transformer, huggingface

I am dealing with multivariate time series forecasting using Transformers.
below is my code step by step:

After some preprocessing and windowing time series dataset …

1- Creating Mask function

```
input_sequence_length = 10 # incoder input sequence
target_sequence_length = 5 # decoder input sequence

tgt_mask = generate_square_subsequent_mask(
    dim1=target_sequence_length,
    dim2=target_sequence_length
   )
src_mask = generate_square_subsequent_mask(
    dim1=target_sequence_length,
    dim2=input_sequence_length
   )
```

2- Positional Encoding

```
class PositionalEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dropout: float = 0.1, 
        max_seq_len: int = 5000, d_model: int = 512,device = device):

        super().__init__()

        self.d_model = d_model
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
        self.batch_first = True  # Assuming batch_first is always True

        position = torch.arange(max_seq_len).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2) * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))

        pe = torch.zeros(1, max_seq_len, d_model)
        pe[0, :, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[0, :, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)

        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)
        
    def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]
        return self.dropout(x)
```

3 - Creating Transformers Encoder and Decoder with Pytorch

```
class TimeSeriesTransformer(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, 
        input_size: int,
        dec_seq_len: int,
        out_seq_len: int= 5, # target_sequence_length
        dim_val: int=512,  
        n_encoder_layers: int=2,
        n_decoder_layers: int=2,
        n_heads: int=4,
        dropout_encoder: float=0.2, 
        dropout_decoder: float=0.2,
        dropout_pos_enc: float=0.1,
        dim_feedforward_encoder: int=512,
        dim_feedforward_decoder: int=512,
        num_predicted_features: int=1
        ): 

        super().__init__() 

        self.dec_seq_len = dec_seq_len

        self.encoder_input_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=input_size, 
            out_features=dim_val 
            )

        self.decoder_input_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=num_predicted_features,
            out_features=dim_val
            )  
        
        self.linear_mapping = nn.Linear(
            in_features=dim_val, 
            out_features=num_predicted_features
            )

        # Create positional encoder
        self.positional_encoding_layer = PositionalEncoder(
            d_model=dim_val,
            dropout=dropout_pos_enc
            )

        encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
            d_model=dim_val, 
            nhead=n_heads,
            dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward_encoder,
            dropout=dropout_encoder,
            batch_first=True
            )

        self.encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(
            encoder_layer=encoder_layer,
            num_layers=n_encoder_layers, 
            norm=None
            )

        decoder_layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(
            d_model=dim_val,
            nhead=n_heads,
            dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward_decoder,
            dropout=dropout_decoder,
            batch_first=True
            )

        self.decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(
            decoder_layer=decoder_layer,
            num_layers=n_decoder_layers, 
            norm=None
            )

    def forward(self, src: Tensor, tgt: Tensor, src_mask: Tensor=None, 
                tgt_mask: Tensor=None) -> Tensor:

        src = self.encoder_input_layer(src) 
      
        src = self.positional_encoding_layer(src) 
        src = self.encoder(src=src)
        
        decoder_output = self.decoder_input_layer(tgt)
        decoder_output = self.decoder(
            tgt=decoder_output,
            memory=src,
            tgt_mask=tgt_mask,
            memory_mask=src_mask
            )
        decoder_output = self.linear_mapping(decoder_output) 
        
        return decoder_output
```

4 - model

```
model = TimeSeriesTransformer(
    input_size=7,
    dec_seq_len=5,
    num_predicted_features=1,
    ).to(device)
```

5 - creating loader # befor created in the preprocessing step

```
i, batch = next(enumerate(train_loader))
src, trg, trg_y = batch
src = src.to(device) # shape [5 , 10 , 7] , batch size , encoder sequence len , number of feature
trg = trg.to(device) # shape [5 , 5 , 7], batch size , decoder sequence len , number of feature
```

6 - output of the model

```
 output = model(
        src=src,
        tgt=trg,
        src_mask=src_mask,
        tgt_mask=tgt_mask
        )
    trg_y = trg_y.to(device) # [5 , 5 , 1] , batch size , deocder or output sequence len , number predicted feature
```

7 - Finally the raised error is like below

```
output = model(
    src=src,
    tgt=trg,
    src_mask=src_mask,
    tgt_mask=tgt_mask
    )
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[348], line 1
    output = model(

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1518 in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1527 in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)

  Cell In[344], line 80 in forward
    decoder_output = self.decoder_input_layer(tgt)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1518 in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1527 in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py:114 in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (25x7 and 1x512)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs at `decoder_output = self.decoder_input_layer(tgt)`

`self.decoder_input_layer` is defined as:

```py
self.decoder_input_layer = nn.Linear(
    in_features=num_predicted_features,
    out_features=dim_val
    )
```

In your code, `num_predicted_features=1` and `dim_val=512`. This means your linear layer expects an input of size `(-1, 1)` and produces an output of size `(-1, 512)`.

In your code, you say that `tgt` is of size `(5, 5, 7)`. This size is incompatible with the linear layer, giving the error.

Comment: Thank you, it is resolved now. The problem was exactly as you mentioned, related to the input of the decoder. I modified the decoder_input_layer's input_features from num_predicted_features to an input size, which changed from 1 to 7.